# How to add Groups to ListView, then add Items to Groups

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm trying to display Groups in my ListView Control and even though I can add them *manually* in the Designer view, this is not beneficial to me because I need to add items and groups dynamically at runtime, and I couldn't possibly know what groups will be added at runtime.

I've searched online, and to my surprise there is very little information (that makes any kind of sense) that I can find. And the only sample code I could find that looked like it was made for what I want to do is from the offline documentation I downloaded with Visual Studio, and that code sample has 18 compile-time errors and 2 main entry points!

So, how do we dynamically add groups at runtime to a ListView Control, then add items to the list.

So you have a good idea of exactly what I'm trying to accomplish, I've attached an image, below:

[image: ListView with Groups Sample]

Answer (score 3):

A way to do this is to add ListViewGroup to your ListView. Then when adding Items to your list view, add a new ListViewItem and specify the group.

```
public class Form1 {
    private ListViewGroup categoryGroup = new ListViewGroup("Categories", HorizontalAlignment.Left);
    private ListViewGroup movieGroup = new ListViewGroup("Movies", HorizontalAlignment.Left);
    private ListViewGroup castGroup = new ListViewGroup("Cast", HorizontalAlignment.Left);

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListView1.BeginUpdate();
        ListView1.Groups.Add(categoryGroup);
        ListView1.Groups.Add(movieGroup);
        ListView1.Groups.Add(castGroup);
        ListView1.EndUpdate();
    }

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListView1.BeginUpdate();
        Category.GetCategories().ForEach(x => ListView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(x.Name, categoryGroup)));
        Movie.GetMovies().ForEach(x => ListView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(x.Name, movieGroup)));
        Cast.GetCast().ForEach(x => ListView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(x.Names, castGroup)));

        ListView1.EndUpdate();
    }
}
```

I'm sure there is a more elegant solution to this, but this should give a decent idea of how to add items to the individual groups.

Answer (score 1):

[How to: Group Items in a Windows Forms ListView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ezh1batz(v=vs.100).aspx)

Or a long verbose walk through:

[Grouping ListView items dynamically](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/853a6a/grouping-listview-items-dynamically/)

Comment: The "How To" from Microsoft does not work - no way to get the "odd" and "even", not even talking about the sample in question. First, they do not say how to set the View property, nor do they say how all the other properties are set. No matter how I set those is the items are either misaligned, or in case of View.List the Group names disappear. With View.Details there are Groups, but items disappear. This article is no good. The other article's page is broken, instead of showing pictures it shows "1.gif", "2.gif".